The sql statement I wrote for creating a table with few columns is returning an error stating the right parenthesis error. Can someone help me fix it
Oracle error ora-00907 Oracle error ora-00907
I wrote a simple sql statement to create a table with few columns. However the system is throwing a right parenthesis error.I have checked the code, the syntax and ensured there are no typo errors. I am sure the data types declared are also totally correct and there is no error whatsoever. Some help and guidance will be appreciated.

Does int take a size in Oracle SQL?
